# Chrome's Extension - URL bar history

Tags: google-chrome, url

I searched for hours and I cant find any information about how to get my URL bar history.
Even if you remove items from your history - they still available at the url bar auto-complete (Shift + Del remove them).
I am trying to get documents about how to get to that information and delete it (like I clicked Shift+Del).

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done with a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Are you asking to erase the history for omnibox?